# append value to dataframe based on column value in another dataframe

Tags: r

How can I add a column to the years data.frame that contains the appropriate value from the prod data.frame (the prod data.frame is in order based on year starting at 1996). Do I have to create some kind of key-value pair to match things?

```
years <- data.frame(year = c(1996,1996,1997,1997,1998))
prod <- data.frame(prod = c(12,13,14)) #so 1996=12, 1997=13, 1998=14
```

GOAL:

```
year  prod
1996  12
1996  12
1997  13
1997  13
1998  14
```

Comment: Another option `prod[[1]][match(years[[1]], unique(years[[1]]))]`

Comment: Adding to the suggestion from @docendodiscimus: `cbind(year = years, prod = prod[[1]][match(years[[1]], unique(years[[1]]))])`

Comment: @docendodiscimus, Your solution worked great, can you propose it as an answer, and explain how the match and the list reference work?